# Local systems on $\mathbb P^1$ and on the formal punctured disc

Tags: galois-representations, langlands-conjectures, local-fields

Consider the projective curve $\mathbb P^1$ over a finite field $k$.
Consider $\ell$-adic local systems $E$ on $\mathbb P^1\backslash \{0,\infty\}$ such that

a) $E$ is tame at $\infty$

b) The restriction of $E$ to the formal neighbourhood of $0$ corresponds under local Langlands correspondence to a representation $\pi$ of $GL(n,k((t)))$ which has a vector fixed under the 2nd congruence subgroup in $GL(n,k[[t]])$.

Is there a chance that such local systems are in 1-1 correspondence with the corresponding local systems on Spec $k((t))$ (where $t$ as above is a local parameter at $0$)?